# How to get a binary stream by GridFS ObjectId with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I can't figure out how to stream a binary file from GridFS with spring-data-mongodb and its `GridFSTemplate` when I already have the right `ObjectId`.

GridFSTemplate returns either `GridFSResource` (`getResource()`) or `GridFSFile` (`findX()`).

I can get the `GridFSFile` by ID:

```
// no way to get the InputStream?
GridFSFile file = gridFsTemplate.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)))
```

but there is no obvious way how to get an `InputStream` for that `GridFSFile`.

Only `GridFSResource` allows me to get hold of the corresonding `InputStream` with `InputStreamResource#getInputstream`. But the only way to get a `GridFSResource` is by its `filename`.

```
// no way to get GridFSResource by ID?
GridFSResource resource = gridFsTemplate.getResource("test.jpeg");
return resource.getInputStream();
```

Somehow the `GridFsTemplate` API implies that filenames are unique - which they are not. The `GridFsTemplate` implementation just returns the first element.

Now I'm using the native MongoDB API and everything makes sense again:

```
GridFS gridFs = new GridFs(mongo);
GridFSDBFile nativeFile = gridFs.find(blobId);
return nativeFile.getInputStream();
```

It looks like I'm misunderstanding the fundamental concepts behind the Spring Data Mongo GridFS abstraction. I'd expect (at least) one of the following things to be possible/true:

- get a `GridFSResource` by its ID
- get a `GridFSResource` or `InputStream` for a `GridFsFile` I already have

Am I wrong or is there something odd with this particular piece of the Spring Data MongoDB API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I stumbled upon this, too. And I am actually pretty shocked that the GridFsTemplate has been designed like this...
Anyway, my ugly "solution" to this so far:

```
public GridFsResource download(String fileId) {
    GridFSFile file = gridFsTemplate.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(fileId)));

    return new GridFsResource(file, getGridFs().openDownloadStream(file.getObjectId()));
}

private GridFSBucket getGridFs() {

    MongoDatabase db = mongoDbFactory.getDb();
    return GridFSBuckets.create(db);
}
```

Note: You have to inject the MongoDbFactory for this to work...

Comment: THE ONLY TRUE SOLUTION ON ALL INTERNET SEA, 

Thank you very very very very very very very very much

Comment: Yeah, I did exactly the same ... just copy the getGridFs function from the spring project an implement a new getResource. They should add that to the original code.

Comment: How do you handle mediaType with this solution? Thanks

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who thinks there's a surprising impedance mismatch between the Mongo capabilities of GridFS and Spring Data's abstractions around it.

Answer (score 6):

There is a bit mess in these types:

- [GridFSFile](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/gridfs/model/GridFSFile.html) is type from MongoDB driver
- [GridFsResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/gridfs/GridFsResource.html) is type from Spring
- [ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html)    is type from BSON API

From Spring GridFsTemplate [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/17d61004261c388a98bf1cc932318db69073db2f/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/gridfs/GridFsTemplate.java#L228):

```
public getResource(String location) {

    GridFSFile file = findOne(query(whereFilename().is(location)));
    return file != null ? new GridFsResource(file, getGridFs().openDownloadStream(location)) : null;
}
```

There is an ugly solution:

```
@Autowired
private GridFsTemplate template;

@Autowired
private GridFsOperations operations;

public InputStream loadResource(ObjectId id) throws IOException {
    GridFSFile file = template.findOne(query(where("_id").is(id)));
    GridFsResource resource = template.getResource(file.getFilename());

    GridFSFile file = operations.findOne(query(where("_id").is(id)));
    GridFsResource resource = operations.getResource(file.getFilename());
    return resource.getInputStream();
}
```

Comment: i think you retrieve the file by name at last.
if you have 2 files with same name, and you need the 2th, GridFSFile file is the right obj, but GridFsResource resource is find by name. which is it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) for Mongo for the content storage piece on your solution?

Assuming you are using Spring Boot as well as Spring Data Mongo then it might look something like the following:

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-mongo-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Update your Spring Data Mongo entity, with the following attributes:

```
@ContentId
private String contentId;

@ContentLength 
private long contentLength = 0L;

@MimeType
private String mimeType;
```

Add a store interface:

```
@StoreRestResource(path="content")
public interface MongoContentStore extends ContentStore<YourEntity, String> {
}
```

That's all that you need.  When you application starts Spring Content will see the dependencies on the Spring Content Mongo/REST modules and it will inject an implementation of the `MongonContenStore` store for GridFs as well as an implementation of a controller that supports full CRUD functionality and maps those operations down onto the underlying store interface.  The REST endpoint will be available under `/content`.

i.e.

`curl -X PUT /content/{entityId}` will create or update an entity's image

`curl -X GET /content/{entityId}` will fetch the entity's image

`curl -X DELETE /content/{entityId}` will delete the entity's image

There are a couple of getting started guides [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  They use Spring Content for the filesystem but the modules are interchangeable.  The Mongo reference guide is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/mongo-index.html).  And there is a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s).

HTH

Comment: Above articles looks good. Thanks for sharing.Lets say i am uploading an pdf , word, text file etc using above api, Now i want to search file content based on user input.if user entered a text, that is present inside 3 files , so i want to display 3 files. Any suggestion on this.

Comment: Yes, Spring Content has two fulltext indexing modules.  One for solr and one for elasticsearch.  If you include these in your classpath and configure a connection bean to the relevant server then when you add content it will be sent for fulltext indexing which can then later be searched.

Comment: There is a getting started guide here: https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/spring-content-with-fulltext-docs/

Comment: Paul,I implemented solution you refered,but getting this error while searching content ->org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=index_not_found_exception, reason=no such index [spring-content-fulltext-index]]
Because of some modification required I copy code of DefaultMongoStoreImpl and SearchableImpl,Elasticsearch is also running.Please suggest.

Comment: @Anand this error usually means you are running against an incompatible version of elasticsearch.  Spring Content 1.0.x is tested against 6.8.7 and Spring Content 1.1.x is currently tested against 7.8.2 if that is any help?

Comment: Its working now, Thanks, Only issue i am facing is ,if I use spring-content-rest with swagger, its throwing some boot.

Comment: Feel free to raise an issue against Spring Content and then at least we can investigate if the execptions you are seeing are caused by Spring Content, or not.  Might be able to find a workaround.

Comment: Sure,As of now i am facing only swagger issue, if am using @StoreRestResource & swagger, project is not getting started. So to make swagger work i have to make lot of changes and customize onAfterSetContent,onBeforeUnsetContent event.

Comment: I am not sure how @StoreRestResource is causing issues with swagger but that sounds like a bad thing so I would definitely like to see some stack traces for those issues.

Comment: That was problem with swaggerv2, i checked with swaggerv3 , now its working.Thanks for your support.

Comment: No problem.  For any future issues please feel free to raise an issue against our repo.

Comment: Paul- spring content mongodb(for store) + elastic search(for content search) is working fine for me, now i am trying to add s3 also as storage option, but its throwing error that "The specified bucket does not exist", thought i am able to upload with same AmazonS3 bean, Ref - https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/1.2.1/s3-index.html, pls suggest

Comment: Hi @Anand, interesting.  I assume you have set the AWS_BUCKET envar set.  But it sounds like the bucket isn't quite what you expect it to be for some reason.  If you increase the logging on the S3 calls can you see what bucket it is using?

Comment: Hi @Paul, I raised an issue here https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content/issues/700, can you please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data 2.1.0 added an overload of [`getResource()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/gridfs/GridFsTemplate.html#getResource-com.mongodb.client.gridfs.model.GridFSFile-) to `GridFsTemplate` that returns the `GridFsResource` for a given `GridFsFile`.  `GridFsResource` has a method to get the `InputStream`.  Therefore, if you're on at least this version of Spring Data, you can get the `InputStream` by making two calls to the `GridFsTemplate`:

```java
GridFSFile gridFsFile =
        gridFsTemplate.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)));

// In real code, perform necessary null checks in case the file doesn't exist

GridFsResource resource = gridFsTemplate.getResource(gridFsFile);
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

i discovered the solution to this problem!

Just wrap the GridFSFile in a GridFsResource! This is designed to be instantiated with a GridFSFile.

```
public GridFsResource getUploadedFileResource(String id) {
    var file = this.gridFsTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)));
    return new GridFsResource(file);
}

@GetMapping("/{userId}/files/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getUploadedFile(
    @PathVariable Long userId,
    @PathVariable String id
){
    var user = userService
        .getCurrentUser()
        .orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);

    var resource = userService.getUploadedFileResource(id);

    try {
        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(resource.getContentType()))
            .contentLength(resource.contentLength())
            .body(resource);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }


}
```

The great advantage of this is, that you can directly pass the GridFsResource to a ResponseEntity due to the fact, that the GridFsResource extends a InputStreamResource.

Hope this helps!

Greetings
Niklas

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the GridFSFile in a GridFsResource or use this

```
GridFSFile file = gridFsTemplate.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(fileId)));
GridFsResource resource = gridFsTemplate.getResource(file);
return resource.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

getResource(com.mongodb.client.gridfs.model.GridFSFile file) function of GridFsTemplate returns the GridFsResource for a GridFSFile.

```
GridFSFile gridfsFile= gridFsTemplate.findOne(new 
Query(Criteria.where("filename").is(fileName)));
GridFsResource gridFSResource= gridFsTemplate.getResource(gridfsFile);
InputStream inputStream= gridFSResource.getInputStream();
```

If the above one is not working in some higher version of Spring boot, use the bellow:

```
GridFSFile gridfsFile= gridFsTemplate.findOne(new 
Query(Criteria.where("filename").is(fileName)));
//or
GridFSFile  gridfsFile = 
gridFsOperations.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("filename").is(fileName)));
 return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentLength(gridFsdbFile.getLength())
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("image/png"))
                .body(gridFsOperations.getResource(gridFsdbFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api ")
public class AttachmentController {

private final GridFsOperations gridFsOperations;

@Autowired
public AttachmentController(GridFsOperations gridFsOperations) {
    this.gridFsOperations = gridFsOperations;
}

@GetMapping("/file/{fileId}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile(@PathVariable String fileId) {
GridFSFile file = 
gridFsOperations.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(fileId)));

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentLength(file.getLength())
            .body(gridFsOperations.getResource(file));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but trying to do this in 2019 using WebFlux, I had to do the following

```
  public Mono<GridFsResource> getImageFromDatabase(final String id) {

    return Mono.fromCallable(
        () ->
            this.gridFsTemplate.getResource(
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        this.gridFsTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id))))
                    .getFilename()));
  }
```

Which will give you a `Mono` which can be returned in a controller. I'm sure there is a nicer solution however.

Answer (score -3):

```
GridFSDBFile file = ... 
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
file.writeTo(baos);
byte[] ba = baos.toByteArray()
```