# GridFsResource InputStream not returning any bytes

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a simple test using Spring Data MongoDB to store an object in the repository and then read it out.   The test if failing because when I try to read the content from the object, the input stream isn't returning any data, even through the GridFsResource object says the size is 33 bytes (which is correct).

EDIT:   I created a new project from spring boot initializr....maven/java 8/boot 2.2.5, only dependency is Spring Data Mongo DB.  After downloading, I only added a test document to the test resources, and one test method.  Still fails.

EDIT2:  Updated example project to use in memory mongo server.  [Download Link.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tQkHmLTWh_fHYv_TaLxB2UyUaPE_bzSB/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my simple test case:

```
    @Test
    public void test_getDocument() throws Exception {

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("grid/testDocument.txt");
        String fileContent = "This is a Test Document";

        ObjectId reference = gridFsOperations.store(resource.getInputStream(), "foo.txt");

        List<GridFSFile> files = new ArrayList<>();
        GridFSFindIterable result = gridFsOperations.find(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(reference)));
        result.into(files);
        assertEquals(1, files.size());
        assertEquals(reference, files.get(0).getObjectId());

        GridFSFile fsFile = files.get(0);
        assertEquals("foo.txt", fsFile.getFilename());
        GridFsResource fsResource = new GridFsResource(fsFile);

        assertEquals(fsFile.getLength(), fileContent.length());   // This test passes.

        String fileValue = StreamUtils.copyToString(fsResource.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        assertEquals(fileValue, fileContent);  // This test fails
    }
```

Logs from test run:

```
16:36:55.233 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
16:36:55.242 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
16:36:55.263 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
16:36:55.274 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
16:36:55.277 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/example/mongo/demo/MongoTestApplicationTests-context.xml] does not exist
16:36:55.277 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/example/mongo/demo/MongoTestApplicationTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
16:36:55.277 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
16:36:55.278 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests]: MongoTestApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
16:36:55.300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests]
16:36:55.343 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/n0079911/data/services/demo/target/classes/com/example/mongo/demo/MongoTestApplication.class]
16:36:55.344 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplication for test class com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests
16:36:55.410 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests]: using defaults.
16:36:55.411 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
16:36:55.415 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
16:36:55.420 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@797cf65c, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@31bcf236, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4b3ed2f0, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@4fad9bb2, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@517d4a0d, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@7862f56, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@3a12c404, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@1941a8ff, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@22d7b4f8, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@149dd36b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@38831718, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@2c1156a7]
16:36:55.422 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@6aa3a905 testClass = MongoTestApplicationTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@a22cb6a testClass = MongoTestApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@433defed, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7fd50002, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4007f65e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4b8d604b], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
16:36:55.428 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@6aa3a905 testClass = MongoTestApplicationTests, testInstance = com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests@115667d, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@a22cb6a testClass = MongoTestApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@433defed, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7fd50002, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4007f65e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4b8d604b], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]].
16:36:55.443 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=-1}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-22 16:36:56.686  INFO 26508 --- [           main] c.e.m.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests     : Starting MongoTestApplicationTests on LIBP45P-348786T with PID 26508 (started by n0079911 in /Users/n0079911/data/services/demo)
2020-03-22 16:36:56.686  INFO 26508 --- [           main] c.e.m.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-22 16:36:56.898  INFO 26508 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-22 16:36:56.909  INFO 26508 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 8ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2020-03-22 16:36:57.190  INFO 26508 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2020-03-22 16:36:57.242  INFO 26508 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:481}] to localhost:27017
2020-03-22 16:36:57.244  INFO 26508 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 2, 22]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=4, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=null, roundTripTimeNanos=712909}
2020-03-22 16:36:57.406  INFO 26508 --- [           main] c.e.m.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests     : Started MongoTestApplicationTests in 1.959 seconds (JVM running for 2.77)

2020-03-22 16:36:57.641  INFO 26508 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:482}] to localhost:27017


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :
Actual   :This is a Test Document
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1124)
    at com.example.mongo.demo.MongoTestApplicationTests.test_getDocument(MongoTestApplicationTests.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)




2020-03-22 16:36:57.688  INFO 26508 --- [extShutdownHook] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:482}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Is my test flawed?   Why does it fail?

Comment: maybe a look at [data/mongodb/gridfs/GridFsTemplateIntegrationTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/a04821ff90f5a5e4f96294341b3061f5d802db12/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/gridfs/GridFsTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L272) can help.

Comment: Those tests don't have an example where they actually read the data from the document after finding it.

Comment: How about [Line 286](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/a04821ff90f5a5e4f96294341b3061f5d802db12/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/gridfs/GridFsTemplateIntegrationTests.java#L286)?

Comment: I have that same code...except GridFSFile.getInputStream() no longer exists (https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/javadoc/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFSFile.html) in Mongo.  You need to create an GridFsResource (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/gridfs/GridFsResource.html) from the FSFile and get the InputStream from that.  As seen here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153910/how-to-get-a-binary-stream-by-gridfs-objectid-with-spring-data-mongodb. That is what I am doing in my test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `GridFsOperations#getResource(GridFSFile)` instead of `new GridFsResource(fsFile)` to obtain the actual content.

```java
GridFSFile fsFile = gridFsOperations.findOne(query(where("_id").is(reference)));
GridFsResource fsResource = gridFsOperations.getResource(fsFile);
```